# How to play mysic from the list

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to music get the songs from the sd card and displaying the details of the song in the list view and setting itemOnclick Listener in it .I am able to play the song properly ,But when i click a different item in the list view the other song start without stopping the first one here is my code

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Mediafileinfo item = audioList.get(i);
            Uri myUri = Uri.parse(item.getData());


            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {mediaPlayer.reset();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, myUri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                try {
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mediaPlayer.start();

            }
           else if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                   mediaPlayer.reset();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, myUri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried to set isPlaying and if the song is playing it will stop it but that also dont work for me any hint or where I am doing wrong ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare this outside the on item click listener

```
 mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

when you click,you making a new mediaPlayer ,but the new mediaPlayer isn't playing,so there are two mediaPlayer  playing.

Comment: you can bring  mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer() forward.

Comment: only one mediaPlayer  needed.

Comment: Ya u are right I am making a new media player when ever the item is clicked .I did a noob mistake

Comment: mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();                   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
    });